# Cannot read property '_init' of null vue-cropperjs

Tags: vue.js, cropperjs

I have a project that works for Laravel + VueJs. But I am beginner and my skills in using Vue are too low. In this project i have to use cropper-js (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#cropperjs). I found an implementation this library special for vue-js (https://github.com/Agontuk/vue-cropperjs). I copied from package.json one string

```
"vue-cropperjs": "https://github.com/Agontuk/vue-cropperjs.git#master"
```

and execute

> npm install

than, in my app.js, i wrote

> import VueCropper from 'vue-cropperjs';
>     Vue.use(VueCropper);

and after start the application, in console, i see next text

> Cannot read property '_init' of null

Also i tried use that code directly in the component file

```
<template>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"
           style="font-size: 1.2em; padding: 10px 0;"
           @change="setImage($event)"
    />
</div>
</template>
<script>
    import VueCropper from 'vue-cropperjs';
    export default {
        name : 'userfiles',
        data: function(){
        return {
            imgSrc: '',
            cropImg: ''
        }
    },
    methods:{
        setImage(e){
            const file = e.target.files[0];
            if (!file.type.includes('image/')) {
                alert('Please select an image file');
                return;
            }
            if(typeof FileReader === 'function'){
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (event) => {
                    this.imgSrc = event.target.result;
                    this.cropper.replace(event.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }else{
                alert('Sorry, FileReader API not supported');
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

this code i copied from here (https://github.com/Agontuk/vue-cropperjs/blob/master/example/src/App.js).

but now i get

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Anybody can tell what the error is and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Typically you install packages using the instructions provided. `npm install --save vue-cropperjs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like you are not directly copy the [source](https://github.com/Agontuk/vue-cropperjs/blob/master/example/src/App.js). The line `this.cropper.replace(event.target.result);` causes the error. There is no `copper` as `props/data/method/computed/ref` etc in your component.

In the [source](https://github.com/Agontuk/vue-cropperjs/blob/master/example/src/App.js), there is a `render` function which `<vue-cropper ref='cropper' ...>` and later the code use this reference `this.$refs.cropper`. You can find more information about ref [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs).